# Issue when I drag google maps api v3 in OpenGTS

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im using OpenGTS 2.5.3 and I want to use with goole maps as provider maps. I have the api v3 key inserted in the code and google maps appears, but the problem occurs when I want to displace or drag mouse over the map. The map doens't move correctly. Im fact only I can move and zoom 1 or 2 cm.

Someone Could help me?

This is the original code of OpenGTS that I am using:

```
<MapProvider name="googleMaps" 
    active="${Domain.MapProvider.active=true}"
    class="org.opengts.war.maps.jsmap.GoogleMaps"
    key="${Domain.MapProvider.key=MY API KEY}"
    rtPropPrefix="Domain.MapProvider.">

    <Property key="map.fillFrame">true</Property>
    <!-- <Property key="map.width">680</Property>           -->     <!-- map width -->
    <!-- <Property key="map.height">470</Property>          -->     <!-- map width -->
    <Property key="scrollWheelZoom">false</Property>                <!-- enable/disable scroll wheel zoom -->
    <!-- <Property key="google.mapcontrol">http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=true&key=...</Property> -->
    <Property key="google.sensor">true</Property>

    <!-- default zoom/location -->
    <Property key="default.zoom">4</Property>                       <!-- default zoom when no pushpins are displayed -->
    <Property key="default.lat">39.0000</Property>                  <!-- default latitude when no pushpins are displayed -->
    <Property key="default.lon">-96.5000</Property>                 <!-- default longitude when no pushpins are displayed -->

    <!-- Geozone map size/config -->
    <!-- <Property key="zone.map.width">630</Property> -->
    <!-- <Property key="zone.map.height">540</Property> -->
    <Property key="zone.map.multipoint">false</Property>            <!-- [true|false] false==1 point, true=6 points -->
    <Property key="zone.map.polygon">true</Property>                <!-- [true|false] display polygon option -->
    <Property key="zone.map.corridor">false</Property>              <!-- [true|false] display corridor option (not supported) -->

    <!-- include target geozones on map (a pushpin must be in the Geozone for it to be displayed) -->
    <Property key="map.includeGeozones">false</Property>

    <!-- route line -->
    <Property key="map.routeLine">true</Property>                   <!-- include travel route line -->
    <Property key="map.routeLine.color">#FF2222</Property>          <!-- include travel route line color -->
    <Property key="map.routeLine.arrows">false</Property>           <!-- include travel route line arrows (GoogleMaps only - always blue) -->

    <!-- replay -->
    <Property key="replay.enable">true</Property>                   <!-- enable/disable replay -->
    <Property key="replay.interval">1200</Property>                 <!-- replay interval (in milliseconds) -->
    <Property key="replay.singlePushpin">false</Property>           <!-- show only single pushpin during replay -->

    <!-- auto update -->
    <Property key="auto.enable">false</Property>
    <Property key="auto.interval">20</Property>
    <Property key="auto.count">10</Property>

    <!-- use default pushpins -->
    <Pushpins includeDefault="true"/>

    <!-- legend -->
    <Legend type="device" includeDefault="true"/>
    <Legend type="fleet"  includeDefault="true"/>

</MapProvider>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, whenever I loaded a map, it was really difficult to drag it with the mouse (it was possible using the buttons).

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following parameter to the googleMaps MapProvider section

```
<Property key="google.version">3</Property>
```

This forces OpenGTS to use version 3 api from the start.